# sending data from one contract to another smartpy tezos

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I am trying to send data from one contract to another in smartpy

**Remote Contract**

```
import smartpy as sp

class Try(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(mynum = sp.int(0))

    @sp.entry_point
    def add(self,params):
        self.data.mynum = params.num


@sp.add_test(name="try")
def test():
    obj = Try()
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    scenario += obj
```

**Calling Contract / Current Contract**

```
import smartpy as sp

class Try(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(mynum = sp.int(0))

    @sp.entry_point
    def add(self,params):
        c = sp.contract(sp.TRecord(num = sp.TInt),sp.address("KT1X6yVQccrVn8r9PCEbExy21GHwikU7KXn5"),entry_point="add").open_some()

        mydata = sp.record(num = params.num)
        sp.transfer(mydata,sp.mutez(0),c)


@sp.add_test(name="try")
def test():
    obj = Try()
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    scenario += obj
```

**Error**

```
Status: failed

    Error: proto.005-PsBabyM1.michelson_v1.runtime_error
    Error: proto.005-PsBabyM1.michelson_v1.script_rejected
       undefined
```

Remote Contract Address (Use Smartpy explorer) - KT1X6yVQccrVn8r9PCEbExy21GHwikU7KXn5

Calling Contract Address (Use smartpy explorer) - 
KT1EJCF1iU4jQkJZz1FWTbaPf7TZYGNNhXbF

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the entry_point annotation "add" in the calling contract when the first contract has only one entry point.
This is annoying but I believe it is necessary because of Tezos annotations.

That being said, we may in the future check `sp.contract(...)` at origination time when possible. This would have failed earlier.

I've originated one such contract KT1EJhzNtwn7WALCCqp3u2pEUGyNrqfWyUHJ and successfully interacted with your initial contract.

For people not using SmartPy explorer (e.g., https://smartpy.io/test2/explore.html?address=KT1EJhzNtwn7WALCCqp3u2pEUGyNrqfWyUHJ), the network in question is Babylonnet.